# How to move docs using drag and drop from the search results in Google Drive?

Tags: google-drive

Refer to this annotated screenshot and the explanation that follows:

[image: Annotated sceenshot]

This is what I did and what I expect to see happen:

1. Go into Google Drive, and in the search box, type in a few words to search for a document. Anything will do here just to show some files. But arrange it so that both documents *and* folders are shown. One of those folders will be the target of a subsequent move operation.
2. Click the left mouse down on a document, and hold it down, then drag it to one of those folders that are shown in the search results.
3. At this point, I expect to see something change so that it will allow me to drop it into the destination folder.  But it does not work.
4. But click on a folder that the item exists within, and then try it, then we see that drag and drop works.

I know there is a context menu,that I can use to move the document. I don't want to use that because it is painful: I have to then scroll and scroll to find the destination folder (and I have a lot of folders). When I use the search feature, I will have a mix of documents and folders, and it is one of those folders that I want to drag a document into.

Is this a bug (or unimplemented feature) in Google Drive or am I missing something obvious?

I suspect this is a bug so I posted into the [Google Drive forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/drive/report-a-problem/drive-in-your-browser/windows/GbnoZqRWx5E).

Comment: I don't have a problem with this. What browser are you using?

Comment: I'm using Firefox latest version.

Comment: I have added the annotated screenshot in to the description.  I just tried to reproduce this on Firefox running under Windows 7. Version info for that version of Firefox is: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:36.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/36.0.